# How to keep variable's value using localstorage?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, local-storage

For example I have draggable here and once the if statement is true it will store 1 in winner variable. But after refreshing the page or going to another page it will still keep the value because I'm planning to call the variable again. How to keep variable's value in local storage?

Comment: This really isn't hard to research. There is nothing complicated about localStorage API and documentation is not hard to find

Comment: first time hearing localstorage and my prof never teached us that

Comment: do you need a prof to tell you to paste it into google or any other search engine?

Comment: tried searching on google w3schools and stackoverflow i dont understand it

Comment: OK, would do better explaining what you don't understand rather than asking a broad question that doesn't reflect any attempt at some research

Comment: i attempted researching

Answer (score 1):

Set the variable to local storage :

```
//you store with a key ie. "winner" and then the value (your variable)
localStorage.setItem("winner", winner)

//then to get the value
winner = localStorage.getItem("winner")
```

Comment: how do i call it on html? sorry im not familiar to localstorage

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var winner = localStorage.getItem('winner');
if (!winner && winner !== 0) {
    localStorage.setItem('winner', 0);
}
$("#car").draggable({
    revert: "invalid", containment: "#wrapper",
    start: function(event, ui){
        if(!done) return false;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui){
        if($(".correct").length == $(".drop").length){
            setTimeout(function(){
                 $('#win').text(winner+' '+'stars'+' '+'earned');
            },500);
            winner = localStorage.getItem('winner');
            winner++;
            localStorage.setItem('winner', winner);

            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    } 
});
```

If you establish a local storage item "winner" and make sure it is initialized as an integer, you can increment it and use that item to persist across page request.

Comment: how will i see if winner value is retained even if i refresh page?

Comment: It will be retained, local storage is not cleared until the user empties explicitly this data.  Open the dev console and type: localStorage.getItem('winner'); abnd you will see the value.